# How are OpenGL programs debugged?

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, opengl-3

I'm trying to find what is causing a segfault when glDrawArrays is called (as gdb says) in my simple program.

When I use the OpenGl calls directly, the program runs fine. 
But when I wrap them up into two classes (under construction, of vao and vbo) the program segfaults.

So, in my wrappers, I definitly disabled something or set something I'm not supposed to.

My question is, how do I get some diagnostics that will help me pinpoint the source of the problem ?

I'm looking for something similar to what glGetShaderiv does, but for vao and vbo s, that will tell me if I have..say.. unbound a buffer by mistake.

[I'm not posting the code here, but if any of you want to donate some time by testing a segfaulting example, [here is a tar.gz of the source](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0oubbp-MVYOWEJVVXF5NVE4MlE) . You'll need working libraries of sfml-2.0rc, glew  and gcc>=4.6 .]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VBO data must be alloocated when you call glVertexAttribPointer. But because you call it afterwards, the previously called glVertexAttribPointer will instruct VAO to point to invalid location - thus the crash during the drawing.

See how you are calling the code in your commented section - first the glBufferData, and only then glVertexAttribPointer.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.(Along with the fact that I was calling glBindVertexArray with a zero argument , before I was done with all the operations on a VAO.)

Answer (score 4):

Try out a program like GDEBugger: http://www.gremedy.com/

It allows you to easily check the state of OpenGL and give you good diagnostics.

Comment: Seems interesting, I'll give it a try. (Also looks like it would be a wonderful tool for learning OpenGl smoothly!)

Comment: I tried to get my program running in it for quite some time, but it wasn't cooperating much with my OS. (/usr/lib and /usr/lib64 issues, which a soft link didn't fix). I'll try to get it running the next time I run into a serious problem.